# Youtube Video 5*5 Mosaic with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've just started to learn Html and CSS and I had an idea of a website where you could input a youtube link and it show the video in a 5*5 mosaic with the video also on the background . It has no use whatsover but I really want to make it !
Let me explain [This is what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlD0v.png) This is what I did

```css
img#bgimg { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover; 
}
 
 
.stick {
 
 
 height:158px;
 width:280px;
 line-height: 0;


 
}
.center{
 
 height:158px;
 width:280px;
 display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>schema</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schema.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id="bgimg" >
<source src="">
</img>
<div>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="7.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="8.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="9.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="12.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="13.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="14.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="17.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="18.jpg"></img>
 <img class="center" src="19.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 <img class="stick" src="black.jpg"></img>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to center everything using p align="center" but I want to use CSS if possible also the 7/8/9/12/13/14/17/18/19 squares are supopsed to be one big square but I didn't managed to do it .
all the other squares are supposed to be the video also 
How can I do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would you like this code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.center{
    margin:50px 50px 0px 50px;
    height:158px;
    width:280px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
 </style>
<title>schema</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schema.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <video width="400" controls>
 <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">


    </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's already better ! How can I make a mosaic out of this ? and what about the middle one ?